# E/WM-WorkerFactory: Could not instantiate com.isopod.gateauth.UnifyIDAPIHandler$ModelTrainer

Tags: java, android, worker

So I'm trying to schedule a task using the standard android work library, but I get the following error trace

```
E/WM-WorkerFactory: Could not instantiate com.isopod.gateauth.UnifyIDAPIHandler$ModelTrainer
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2327)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2166)
        at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:242)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:136)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/WM-WorkerWrapper: Could not create Worker com.isopod.gateauth.UnifyIDAPIHandler$ModelTrainer
```

I'm using the standard work library. I've seen other users have this problem when trying to inject a custom initializer, but I believe I am using the default library, that should be able to initialize properly on its own

Here is my dependencies in my app level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'id.unify.sdk:sdk-gaitauth:1.3.8'

    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.4.0"

    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Here is the code for the class that I'm trying to use

```java
public class ModelTrainer extends Worker {

    public ModelTrainer (Context context, WorkerParameters params){
        super(context, params);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        try {
            if (curStatus == GaitAuthStatus.READY_TO_TRAIN) {
                gaitModel.train();
                curStatus = GaitAuthStatus.TRAINING;
            } else if (curStatus == GaitAuthStatus.TRAINING) {
                gaitModel.refresh();
            }

        } catch (GaitModelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Result.failure();
        }

        if (gaitModel.getStatus() == GaitModel.Status.READY) {
            curStatus = GaitAuthStatus.READY;
        } else if (gaitModel.getStatus() == GaitModel.Status.FAILED) {
            return Result.failure();
        }

        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

and here is my code for starting the work

```
WorkRequest trainModelRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(ModelTrainer.class).build();

WorkManager.getInstance(mainActivity.getApplicationContext()).enqueue(trainModelRequest);
mainActivity.addTextToScreen("Model training started");
```

It's also worth noting that I get a bunch of strange looking messages android studio run log:

```
W/isopod.gateaut: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (light greylist, reflection)
W/isopod.gateaut: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (light greylist, reflection)
I/org.libsodium.jni.NaCl: librarypath=/system/lib
W/pool-3-thread-1: type=1400 audit(0.0:32027): avc: denied { read } for uid=10158 name="cache" dev="dm-0" ino=31 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c158,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:cache_file:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
W/pool-3-thread-1: type=1400 audit(0.0:32028): avc: denied { read } for uid=10158 name="cache" dev="dm-0" ino=31 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c158,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:cache_file:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
I/RootBeer: LOOKING FOR BINARY: /data/local/su Absent :(
    LOOKING FOR BINARY: /data/local/bin/su Absent :(
    LOOKING FOR BINARY: /data/local/xbin/su Absent :(
    LOOKING FOR BINARY: /sbin/su Absent :(
    LOOKING FOR BINARY: /su/bin/su Absent :(
    LOOKING FOR BINARY: /system/bin/su Absent :(
    LOOKING FOR BINARY: /system/bin/.ext/su Absent :(
    LOOKING FOR BINARY: /system/bin/failsafe/su Absent :(
    LOOKING FOR BINARY: /system/sd/xbin/su Absent :(
    LOOKING FOR BINARY: /system/usr/we-need-root/su Absent :(
    LOOKING FOR BINARY: /system/xbin/su Absent :(
    LOOKING FOR BINARY: /cachesu Absent :(
    LOOKING FOR BINARY: /datasu Absent :(
    LOOKING FOR BINARY: /devsu Absent :(
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
I/chatty: uid=10158(com.isopod.gateauth) FinalizerDaemon identical 1 line
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
    A resource failed to call end. 
W/isopod.gateaut: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
W/isopod.gateaut: Accessing hidden field Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->theUnsafe:Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (light greylist, reflection)
D/ModelStore: Saved model d9d51fd3-2a9b-4af1-97f3-3d67424e8785 into storage, model data length 0 bytes
```

Can anyone give me some idea as to what might be going on? I'm proper confused. I pretty much followed the setup guide and example in the android docs, so if I'm having this problem I'm sure many others are as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting an answer by the lovely u/Zhuinden on reddit,

If this is a worker, you need to have a constructor that takes Context, WorkerParameters, and NO OTHER PARAMETERS. Just these two.

In your case, the issue is that your class is an inner class, but in Java, that means it also has a reference to its parent. You need to define it as static class

Indeed, adding static to the class definition fixed the problem, but since I wanted to pass data through it I made it an independent public class and used the workmanager data class to pass parameters